# Clang compiles code using std::stoi in c++98 mode

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++, c++98

I need to compile my cpp in C++98, not C++11 for my school project.
So I used `-std=c++98` to compile:

`CPPFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++98`

but I made a mistake and use the C++11 `std::stoi` function.

`i = std::stoi(index);`

I tried without the `-std=c+=98 flag` but it didn't change anything.
I am working on MAC 10.12.6

My code compiles without any warning or any error.

If I am not mistaken, clang should shout at me for using a C++11 function.
Why?

edit clang version:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: What version of clang are you using?  I cannot reproduce [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5a41adee01b448a)

Comment: What is `i`? What is `index`? Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: (You should be using `CXXFLAGS` for that, `CPPFLAGS` is supposed to be for preprocessor directives.)

Comment: Why it's useful here ???  i is a int and index is a string. ok i will use CXXFLAGS but don't change anything

Comment: @AodrenBARY it is useful because we are not good at guessing. It's always a good idea to post a [MCVE].

Comment: It should compile under the c11 standard but not under the c98 standard. I suppose Mat's comment applies here. Try to use `CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++98` (instead of `CPPFLAGS = ...`).

Comment: I tried but also compile without warning `clang++ -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++98 -o phonebook Phonebook.class.cpp Contact.class.cpp main.cpp`

Comment: @AodrenBARY please update your question and put all relevant information _there_. It could be a problem with the toolset you use. I cannot check, I don't have clang nor a mac. You can check [__here__](https://godbolt.org/g/6DC8HX) and play around with different compilers and compiler flags.

Comment: See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9anddj3so) it doesn't compile in C++98 mode, gives compile error, and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Whn5M74TK) same program compiles in C++11 mode. So your error actually appears on GodBolt Linux servers with latest Clang.

Comment: @Arty The issue described here is specific to libc++. Add `-stdlib=libc++` on godbolt.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, it seems that with with libc++ this C++98 compile error doesn't appear. So probably by mistake libc++ didn't exclude std::stoi from C++98 compilation, didn't put necessary Guard macros to exclude this function from C++98.