# Why does the -std=c++98 flag sometimes not work?

Tags: c++, c++98

The situation is as follows:
I want to create a simple c++ program, but it has to use *only* C++98 functions.
I am using `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`.
I am using `c++` as compiler
I am using the following flags for compiling:
`-Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c++98 -pedantic-errors`

Now if I am using the function `stoi()` from `<string>`, compiling will fail, as expected, because `stoi()` is C++11, as you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

---

But here comes the weird behavior that I am not able to understand:
using `round` or `roundf` from `<cmath>` won't trigger the `-std=c++98` flag, even though, from what I can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), all `round` functions are C++11.

Is there any good explanation why this is happening?

---

EDIT:
as [jjramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1643973/jjramsey) mentioned, there is the chance that the standard-C-function of `round` was used, so the `-std=c++98` flag will have no effect on that.
Can anyone confirm this theory?

Comment: Why only c++98?

Comment: Are you use old-school C doesn't have a round function?

Comment: Maybe it's a difference between C and C++ headers?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563993/clang-compiles-code-using-stdstoi-in-c98-mode but can't be used as a target since it doesn't have an upvoted/accepted answer. I'll close that as a dupe of this one instead.

Comment: `round()` and `roundf()` are C functions. Officially, they're from the C99 standard, but I think they've been around before then.

Comment: @cigien However, that question is specifically about `std::stoi` not giving an error, which according to this question does. The issue in the linked question is specific to libc++, while OP here seems to be using libstdc++.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, yeah, I think you're right. I've reopened it for now. (BTW, if you could edit in a small snippet to that other question demonstrating the behavior, it would be useful.)

Comment: In your `cmath`/`math.h` header file, what `#if`s/`#ifdef`s/related is `round`/`fround` in, if any?

Comment: @Cristik because it is a school project and we are limited to only use C++98

Comment: @tblaase Which is a bad way to teach C++ in 2022. C++11 changed significantly how idiomatic C++ is written.

Comment: @user17732522 not if it is the first contact to C++ and they just want us to keep it simple. On the next projects this C++98 limitation is gone and we are free to use anything we want.

Comment: I should point out that the complexity of a *language* does not translate to complexity of the *code* written in that language. As an extreme example, brainfuck is an extremely simple language that can be understood in less than an hour, but writing even the simplest program in it is extremely difficult. Yes, C++98 was a simpler version of the standard, but a lot of the code written in that version becomes much simpler in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing stopped a compiler from implementing anything pre-standard.   For example, Visual Studio 2010 was not a standard C++11 compiler, yet implemented (to some extent) lambdas.

The only thing to expect from a C++98 flag is that all (hopefully) features of C++98 are implemented.  Anything beyond that is just a pre-standard C++11/14/17, etc "bonus" that the compiler has implemented.

Of course, these bonuses were not official, and most were based on a draft of the future C++ standard.  Once the C++ standard for 11/14/17, etc. came to be, a lot of those features introduced in those older compilers were either non-standard, didn't work properly, or missing.

Comment: so there is no way to prevent the compiler from compiling when non C++98 function was used?

Comment: I don't think there is anything "official" (in whatever sense) about what the standard version flags should do, but I don't think the standard library is allowed to introduce a name that is not reserved or described in the standard into the global namespace scope. That would break valid programs.

Comment: @tblaase -- I suggest you take your final code, go over to [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/), and attempt to compile your code using a very early g++ version of the compiler (one that could only support C++98, and probably one that didn't have the `-std` setting available).  Then fix any errors that have to do with using a modern feature.